# What is the proper (measure theoretic) definition of a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variable, measure-theory

(1) If we believe the following link: [http://www.columbia.edu/~md3405/DT_Risk_2_15.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Emd3405/DT_Risk_2_15.pdf)
Then a random variable is a map from a probability/measurable space to a metric space, i.e.
[image: Columbia definition of a random variable]

(2) If we believe the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition
Then a random variable is a map from a probability/measurable space to a measurable space, i.e.
[image: Wikipedia definition of a random variable]

Definition of a measurable space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space

Definition of a metric space: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition

The definition of a measurable space being different from the definition of a metric space, well I am confused...

What is the proper definition of a random variable (1) or (2)?
Is there a way to unify those two definitions?

Comment: The sigma-algebra $\mathfrak B$ generated by Borel sets in a metric space $X$ makes $(X,\mathfrak B)$ measurable, thereby exhibiting the first definition as a special (but still far-ranging) case of the second definition.  Both definitions are more than general enough to handle almost any statistical application, so there's no material difference between them and the underlying concepts are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could depend on the authors and/or on the context.

Me and others are usually considering that *a random variable is the equivalence class of a measurable map from a probability space to a **separable** metric space*, for the "almost surely equal" equivalence relation.

Why the separability assumption? Because, if $(E,d)$ is the metric space in question,

- this assumption ensures that the event $\{X = X'\}$ is measurable when $X$ and $X'$ are two measurable $E$-valued maps;
- this assumption ensures that $d(X,X')$ is measurable, and this allows to define the convergence in probability.

When the state space of a measurable map is not a separable metric space, some authors say that this map is a *random element*.